# UITableViewHeaderFooterView can't change custom background when loading from nib

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've created a custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView and successfully load from nib into my UITableView but always get this message

> "Setting the background color on UITableViewHeaderFooterView has been
>   deprecated. Please use contentView.backgroundColor instead."

Here the code for loading my custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   KTHeaderFooterViewIphone customHeaderIphone* = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"KTHeaderFooterViewIphone" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    customHeaderIphone.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];  // this code worked, but the message above always show
    customHeaderIphone.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];  // this code doesn't work, nothing's happened
    customHeaderIphone.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customHeader.png"]];  // this code doesn't work too, I can't change custom background image
    return customHeaderIphone;
```

}

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Did you set the "Background Color" attribute on the footer view in your nib? If so, set that to "Default".

Also you may want to consider doing

```
customHeaderIphone.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customHeader"]];
```

and not setting the backgroundColor at all. This is Apple's preferred method according to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewHeaderFooterView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewHeaderFooterView/backgroundView) link.

Comment: Set the Background Color to Default make it work like a charm, thank u :D